# Perl regex to match alt attribute as mandatory but sometimes alt attribute comes before src attribute and sometimes after src attribute

Tags: regex, perl, html-parsing

I am facing a problem with Perl regex. On an img element, I want to match the rel, class, alt  src attribute. But alt attribute should be mandatory match if alt attribute exist then its text should be fetched. But I am facing problem with alt attribute existence, on Firefox and chrome alt attribute exists after src attribute and on IE browser it exists before src attribute.

As I want alt attribute as mandatory match but sometimes it comes before src attribute and sometimes after src attribute. Below is the img element source. Please help!

On Chrome and Firefox:

```
<img rel="lightbox[45876]" src="/file?id=13455" class="bbc_img" alt="effectgames777.jpg">
<img rel="lightbox[45876]" src="/file?id=13455" class="bbc_img">
```

On IE browsers:

```
<img rel="lightbox[45876]" class="bbc_img" alt="effectgames777.jpg" src="/file?id=13455">
<img rel="lightbox[45876]" class="bbc_img" src="/file?id=13477">
```

I have created below perl regex but it is not matching alt attribute as mandatory. please help!

```
<img(?:|\s+rel="[^"]*")(?:|\s+class="[^"]*")(|\s+alt="([^"]*)") src\=\"(http\:\/\/domain\.com\/(\d+)\/thumb\/(\d+)|\/file\?id\=(\d+))\"(?:|\s+class="[^"]*")(|\s+alt="([^"]*)")\>
```

Comment: Congratulations, you've begun to learn why parsing HTML with regexes makes no sense at all.

Comment: **Don't use regular expressions to parse HTML**. You cannot reliably parse HTML with regular expressions, and you will face sorrow and frustration down the road. As soon as the HTML changes from your expectations, your code will be broken. See http://htmlparsing.com/perl for examples of how to properly parse HTML with Perl modules that have already been written, tested and debugged.

Comment: Thanks! but I have need to fix this using regex.

Comment: Why is that?  Why does it have to use a regex?

Comment: This is client requirement to use regex.  so I will have to fix it. Please help if you can!

Comment: I think you should be able to do what you want with a lookaround operator in the regexp.

Comment: Others already pointed out that you should not parse HTML with a regular expression. But there is another secret of regular expressions: there is usually no need to solve multiple problems with a single regex. Perl is great. It will even allow you to have multiple regular expressions in one single script.

Answer (score 2):

Does it have to be just one regex only?

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = q{<img  rel="relfoo"  src="srcfoo">};

my @m;
$s =~ m{
  <img \s+ 
    ( 
      ((\w+)(?{push @m, $^N})) 
      = 
      "( ([^"]*) (?{push @m, $^N}) )" 
      \s* 
    )+
  >
}x;
my %h = @m;
print Dumper \%h;
die "alt is mandatory..\n" if !exists $h{alt};
```

output

```
$VAR1 = {
          'rel' => 'relfoo',
          'src' => 'srcfoo'
        };
alt is mandatory..
```

Comment: Exactly. Not only do people want to solve every problem with a regular expression, they also tend to want to solve it with a *single* regular expression.